# Requirements for review queues

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

Since gaining access to the review queues, and starting my arduous journey to learn the rules of the site (to make good reviews, and to clean up the site), I've found that the biggest frustrations that I've had, has been in the review queues.

The one that currently plagues me the most, is the [VLQ queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts). After reading [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue), I feel I've gained a better understanding of how this queue should work. As a result of this, and talking with peers, I've come up with several recommendations that I'd like to see implemented:

- A requirement to view a page to read about the queue and how posts should be treated (And possibly a test/quiz after). Until I read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue), I was taking my best guess, but was definitely getting things wrong.
- A way to flag users who you feel have gotten a review completely wrong. In this case, it would just send a friendly feed like "Another user has felt that you may have done this review correctly. Please review, so that you can be sure to make the correct decision.".
- A way to flag moderators to reverse bad reviews. I've seen several people hop on the "recommend deletion" band wagon, and review towards deletion, when the user did attempt to answer the question. If a mod reviews, and finds the post should be restored, then all users (That recommended deletion in case of reversal from deletion, or looks ok in case of reversal from reversal of "should be deleted"), should get a notification: "A review you voted on, was reviewed by a moderator and found to be incorrect. Please read [this post]/* Link to info doc */ on why this was reversed."
- Encouragement to keep around "only answer" answers. If a question has only one answer, then the system should make note of that, and encourage users to only vote for deletion if it isn't an answer at all. I've seen many (Low quality, but attempts to answer) posts deleted through the queue, and it makes the question look abandoned. Overall, I feel this hurts the site, more than it helps.

Does anyone else have any suggestions? What do you feel the weak/strong points are about the queues?

Answer (score 1):

> A requirement to view a page to read about the queue and how posts should be treated (And possibly a test/quiz after). Until I read this meta post, I was taking my best guess, but was definitely getting things wrong.

In a way, we already have quizzes. They're called [audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review-audits), and while their main purpose is to catch robo-reviewers, they also serve as a test for new reviewers. (No comment on their effectiveness, that's just what the tag says.)

> A way to flag users who you feel have gotten a review completely wrong. In this case, it would just send a friendly feed like "Another user has felt that you may have done this review correctly. Please review, so that you can be sure to make the correct decision.".

If you see a user has a history of poor reviews, [you should flag a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299001/6083675). Moderators can take the appropriate action, either talking with the user or banning them.

The system doesn't make it very easy to communicate with other people who do LQR (unless they leave a comment) or work the edit review queue but you can `@ping` the users who closed a question with comments like normal.

> A way to flag moderators...

We already have this at the bottom of the flag menu. You can request anything you want in the free-form box. Obviously, unless you want to get flag banned, you shouldn't use it [inappropriately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284357/6083675).

You can use the moderator flag on any post if you can't flag the particular thing you want to. Of course, it's best to try to find something from one of the same users if possible.

Nobody needs to reverse a "recommend deletion" vote until after the post is deleted incorrectly. Keep in mind that some reviews were perfectly valid when they were first made, but edits rendered them obsolete.

> Encouragement to keep around "only answer" answers. If a question has only one answer, then the system should make note of that, and encourage users to only vote for deletion if it isn't an answer at all. I've seen many (Low quality, but attempts to answer) posts deleted through the queue, and it makes the question look abandoned. Overall, I feel this hurts the site, more than it helps.

I think that [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/323179) is a bigger issue. To some extent, the presence of an answer makes some people less likely to answer. I'd rather have tumbleweeds than trash anyway (and not just because trash answers prevent me from feeding the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)).

Comment: I'm currently unable to flag moderators on deleted posts. The only way I can view it is through the audit window, and the flag option is unavailable.

Comment: @FrankerZ *You can use the moderator flag on any post if you can't flag the particular thing you want to. Of course, it's best to try to find something from one of the same users if possible.* I already got that covered. Also, I hear that when you reach 10k rep you become able to flag deleted posts.

Comment: Can I get your opinion on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13163570)? Should this have been deleted? Should I flag this answer for mod review? I really hate to see something that is answered get turned into an abandoned question, which the poster did make an attempt at answering it

Comment: [A link to the deleted post](http://imgur.com/a/mgOjw)

Comment: @FrankerZ Yes, that does look like an attempt to answer.